# How to jump to/after Nth comma

Tags: unix, vim, navigation, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most efficient way to reach a spot on sight on VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918601/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reach-a-spot-on-sight-on-vim)

With the code like this:

```
[caret here]create_stage :pay_deposit, due: deposit_due_date, actual: deposit_paid_date, action: 'Deposit', status: status
```

I want to jump right to/before/after the Nth comma (or at least around) of `actual: deposit_paid, [need to be here], action: 'etc'`

What is the most efficient way of doing it? (I currently just `w-w-w` which sucks, also could start counting number of words to use something like `12w` but that just distracts too much).

I don't want search since I do want to keep current search and highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> or use easymotion and probable dupe of [What is the most efficient way to reach a spot on sight on VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918601/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reach-a-spot-on-sight-on-vim/11918800)

Comment: The problem with `f` is that I lose current search and highlight which I want to preserve (as I explicitly stated in the question).

Comment: nope, you don't lose search highlight with f

Comment: Andy, you're right! Don't know why I've always been thinking that it does.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the `f` motion with a `[count]`, so for your example, `3f,` would be the shortest way. (And if you have miscounted, you can correct with `;` and `,`.)

Answer (score 0):

What about searching the comma character?

`/,` and then input a number, say `3` and then type `n` or `N` to locate all commas in the doc?

Comment: `/,` searches one character, what do you mean "input the number"?