# Find specified character several rows down with vim

Tags: vim

[image]

Lets assume I'm at 'X' in the screenshot in vim normal mode. What is the most efficient way to move to the '$' several rows down .Can I use the find command? I realized that f$ just goes to end of line.

Comment: Why not just do `/\$`? That's pretty much exactly what the `/` command is for

Comment: I see ,you have to escape the $ (sorry vim newbie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to reach a spot on sight on VIM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918601/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reach-a-spot-on-sight-on-vim)